# Move 700 mb of files to another directory

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, mv

I have a directory with a lot of mp3 files. I want to be able to move up to 700 mb of those files to another directory. (700 mb is the limit of my blank CD size) I want to create an audio CD.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm having a really hard time trying to understand what you're asking here. Moving or copying or pasting, etc. is trivial for any person with a GUI tool like Files (Nautilus) let alone for someone of your academic level and rep here. Are you perhaps looking for a command/script to make some calculations? Something else? Please edit to clarify. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Yes, 700MB is the typical size for a CD-R/RW and that matters if you intend to create a CD-ROM, a DATA CD with files inside. Files can be of any type and indeed some CD players support reading as audio CD-ROMs with MP3 files inside but they don't have to. **Now, if you to create a CD-Audio then the file size is NOT what you should be looking for but the sum of the the songs' length**. File size is variable depending on bitrate and other factors.

Comment: @ChanganAuto  I want to create an audio CD. So how much of the songs time will fit on a CD?

Comment: About 74 min for the 1st gen 650MB CDs or 80 min for the 700MB ones. The silence/gap between tracks should be accounted for. Some mastering programs allow gapless (useful for many conceptual albums) but I'm not sure the typical ones you'd use in Ubuntu, K3b or Brasero, have settings for that. The last time I did it was more than 20 years ago, sorry.